# IntelliJ JBoss plugin - How to start in debug mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

I have a JBoss plugin running in IntelliJ. It runs fine, however when I try start it in DEBUG mode, I get the following error:

> Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop,
>   reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:8080

I run my application on:

> https://localhost:8443/

So I think I need to change the Detected server https port to `8443`. Or do I need to connect the debug somehow?

Logs:

> `Detected server admin port: 9999 
>   Detected server http port: 8080`

```
/Users/richardmarais/Development/ClubTravel/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/bin/standalone.sh
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /Users/richardmarais/Development/ClubTravel/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50204,suspend=y,server=n
-javaagent:/Users/richardmarais/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n    
=========================================================================    
Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: jdwp /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper /private/var/folders/47/11vw2x9x65z6pyvfrl3d9w1c0000gn/T/idea_classpath1206838148 com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess 56071 com.intellij.javaee.oss.jboss.agent.JBoss7Agent Disconnected from server Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
-Xmx4096m -Xms128m objc[77083]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10b0144c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10b0fb4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. ERROR: Cannot load this JVM TI agent twice, check your java command line for duplicate jdwp options. Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx4096m -Xms128m [2020-04-15 08:32:44,998] Artifact corporateInterface:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment... Detected server admin port: 9999 Detected server http port: 8080
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you append `JAVA_OPTS` somewhere in the environment or the server startup scripts so that the debugger is initialized twice which fails. Only options supplied by IntelliJ IDEA should be used, this one should not be in the options:

`-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n`

Notice that in Run/Debug configuration IntelliJ IDEA is supplying this instead:

`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:50204,suspend=y,server=n`

Inspect the `.sh` startup scripts for your JBoss, they are likely customized to add the old debug options which is causing the issue. Also it's a bad idea to use global environment variables like `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`, I would unset them.

Comment: Thank you. I will try tomorrow morning. I think what you mention is the issue.

Comment: I removed the global `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Xmx4096m -Xms128m"` from the `.bash_profile`. In my JBoss run/debug configuration in IntelliJ I have the `VM Options` set to `-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m`. But I get a `OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`.

Comment: @Richard please try adding `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` to `VM Options`.